# jsf facelet horizontal menu

Tags: jsf, menu, facelets, trinidad

i'm trying to do an horizontal menu, using JSF, Trinidad and facelets,
the menu is created so:

```
<f:facet name="navigation2">
    <tr:navigationTree inlineStyle="display: inline-block; background: white;" 
                       var="item" value="#{menuModel.model}">
        <f:facet name="nodeStamp">
            <tr:commandNavigationItem text="#{messages[item.label]}" 
                                      action="#{item.getAction}" immediate="true"/>
        </f:facet>
    </tr:navigationTree>
</f:facet>
```

the elements are taken from a menagedBean that i can't modify

I tried to play with css but nothing worked

Answer (score 0):

Try switching to a [`<tr:navigationPane>`](http://myfaces.apache.org/trinidad/trinidad-api/tagdoc/tr_navigationPane.html).

```
<f:facet name="navigation2">
  <tr:navigationPane var="item" value="#{menuModel.model}">
    <f:facet name="nodeStamp">
      <tr:commandNavigationItem text="#{messages[item.label]}" 
                                action="#{item.getAction}" immediate="true"/>
    </f:facet>
  </tr:navigationPane>
</f:facet>
```

Answer (score 0):

I also have some problems dealing with a custom menu, what I do is the use of jquery for the menu, so you have to create a XML with the menu and import the .js files and call the jquery library.